# Form_for submits data via params but the controller does not receive it - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and writing code for a shopping cart in rails 4. I am trying to display all items added to the cart with each item in its own row. As part of the data displayed I would like to have a field that displays the quantity of an item ordered and lets the user update the quantity. Currently, the form submits and renders a hash which I can see in the debug, but the data is not being updated in the database. It looks like my controller action does not receive the data.

View

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Your Cart</h1>

<br>
<div class= "cart">

  <% if !@cart_item.nil? %>
    <% @cart_item.each do |cart_item| %>
    <row>
      <% product = Product.find(cart_item.product_id) %>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
      <%= link_to image_tag(product.picture.url(:cart)), product_path(product) %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
      <%= product.name %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">
      <%= cart_item.quantity %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">
      <%= form_for (cart_item) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :quantity %>
        <%= f.number_field :quantity, class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.submit "Update", :controller => 'cart_item', :action => 'quantity_update',class: "btn btn-xs" %>
      <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
      <%= number_to_currency product.price %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">
      <%= link_to 'Delete', cart_item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
      </div>
      <br>
      </row>
      <row>
      <hr>
    </row>
      <% end %>


  <% else %>
    <h4>"Your cart is empty"</h4>
  <% end %>

  You have <%= pluralize(@subtotal, "item")  %> in your cart


</div> 
</container>
</body>
```

Controller

```
class CartItemsController < ApplicationController
  def quantity_update
    @cart_item = CartItem.find(params[:id])
    if !cart_stuff.nil?
      if cart_stuff.save
        flash[:success] = "Quantity updated"
        redirect_to root_path
    else     
        flash[:danger] = "Update did not save"
        redirect_to root_path
      end  
    end
private

  def cart_item_params
    params.require(:cart_item).permit(:quantity, :product_id, :cart_id)
  end


end
```

Debug dump

> !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
>
> utf8: "✓"
>
> _method: patch
>
> authenticity_token: 3DGIMGyRxhzNFSX/WPxeWvNHN7xFHrdAq/+HbQRsFPirfqgP3BY7ZSBIb0VwWlSdmx+ZoDO0DfrLc5IjSR0kmA==
>
> cart_item: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
>     quantity: '3'
>
> commit: Update
>
> controller: cart_items
>
> action: update
>
> id: '83'

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'cart_items/create'

  get 'cart_items/update'

  get 'cart_items/destroy'

  get 'categories/new'

  get 'admin_sessions/new'

  root                'static_pages#home'#'sessions#new'   #'static_pages#home'
  get 'terms'           => 'static_pages#terms'
  get 'contact'         => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'thank_you'       => 'static_pages#thank_you'
  get 'signup'          => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  get 'check'           => 'sessions#new'
  post 'check'          => 'sessions#create'
  get    'adminlogin'   => 'admin_sessions#new'
  post   'adminlogin'   => 'admin_sessions#create'
  delete 'adminlogout'  => 'admin_sessions#destroy'
  get 'cart'            => 'cart_items#update'

  resources :lotnums 
  resources :microposts
  resources :admins
  resources :users
  resources :products
  resources :cart_items, only: [:create, :update, :destroy, :show, :quantity_update]
  resources :categories do
    resources :products
  end
```

Views -> Layouts -> application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all',
                                              'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js">
      </script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

EDITS
-added `cart_item_params` private action code for reference

Comment: You have `quantity_update` method in your controller but you given `update` as an action in the form.

Comment: @Pavan I noticed that the form was pointing to :action => 'create'. I updated the code as follows:<div class="col-xs-1">
      <%= form_for (cart_item) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :quantity %>
        <%= f.number_field :quantity, class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.submit "Update", :controller => 'cart_item', :action => 'quantity_update',class: "btn btn-xs" %>
      <% end %>
      </div>

Comment: @Pavan please clarify, should the f.number_field :quantity be changed to f.number_field :quantity_update or where am I referencing quantity incorrectly?

Comment: Can you update your question with the `routes.rb` code?

Comment: as an aside, your HTML is malformed - there is no `row` element in HTML.

Comment: Where is this 'debug dump' coming from? You also don't change the form target by setting it on the button, you change it by setting it on the `form_for` tag. Some logs of what is going on would also be helpful, as at the moment it's impossible to tell.

Comment: The debug dump comes from `<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>`

Comment: without context of knowing where that code is, it's useless.

Comment: @sevenseacat what additional context should I provide?

Comment: ...the context of knowing where that code is running. After all, your controller action does not render a view, so your ERB code to debug the params is... I have no idea where.

Comment: The delete code, `<%= link_to 'Delete', cart_item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>`, is working just fine. So I can find an item in the database and delete it, but for whatever reason I am unable to retrieve that item and update the quantity field.

Comment: @sevenseacat debug code runs in application.html.erb, this file handles the header, footer and page title.

Comment: you are not hitting that layout with a PATCH request. Please add the requested code to your question.

Comment: using `<%= yield %>` in the application.html.erb file automatically inserts the content of the individual views into the application.html.erb layout.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure whether you copy and pasted, or typed it up here but...

```
@cart_item = CartIem.find(params[:id])
```

In your controller, your missing a 't' from CartItem.find(..).

That would definitely be causing some issues.

Good Luck!

Comment: great catch. Fixed the spelling. also added `:quantity_update` to `resources :cart_items` in routes.rb, when submitting a quantity update the cart re-renders, but the change is not applied. No error messages are triggered.

Comment: Hmmmmm, I've also just spotted that your using cart_stuff to save, but cart_items elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

@Eoghain you are right, i fixed this issue. The ultimate fix of my original issue is to substitute 'cart_item.save' with 'cart_item.update_attributes'. Once I made that change it worked.